# Cannot modify parameter group with DB parameter log expressions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-aurora-serverless

Using AWS Aurora MySQL I'm trying to modify the max_connections to have a minimum of 400 and still scale with the instance type. However, setting the parameter to any value that uses a parameter log expression is giving an error. Even attempting to set it to its same default value from AWS causes the error. What am I missing?

```
aws rds modify-db-cluster-parameter-group \
--db-cluster-parameter-group-name my-cluster-test-copy \
--parameters "ParameterName=max_connections, ParameterValue='GREATEST(400,{log(DBInstanceClassMemory/805306368)*45},{log(DBInstanceClassMemory/8187281408)*1000})', ApplyMethod=immediate"
```

Error:

> An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the ModifyDBClusterParameterGroup operation: The function syntax you have provided (GREATEST(400,{log(DBInstanceClassMemory/805306368)*45},{log(DBInstanceClassMemory/8187281408)*1000})) is invalid. The valid format is: GREATEST(argument1, argument2, ...)

Answer (score 0):

There's a small trick here: You will not be able to change or input manually this kind of "formula", but you can return the original value of the parameter (inside the DB parameter group) using the RESET button.

[image: See here the RESET PARAMETER BUTTON]

This way, it will reset the default value using the "log" formula.